# Xamarin UItest Android - Ids for images do not display in tree

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

This question is for Android. StyleIds have been set for images. Per the documentation, these StyleIds should appear as labels in Android. But they do not.

I have verified that the following exists -

```
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ViewInitializedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.StyleId))
                {
                    e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.StyleId;
                }
            };
```

I am new to Xamarin UItests and have to solve this as the first thing. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Hello, for the sake of future Users/Viewers, if the answer below solves your issue, please mark it as the solution and upvote. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could switch over to using `AutomationId`, it was introduced to Xamarin.Forms in version `2.2` ([release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.2/2.2.0-stable/#AutomationId_Support))

The `AutomationId` property isn't used by Xamarin.Forms so it doesn't affect any functionality to use it as a unique identifier for testing.

Below is a sample using `AutomationId` on an image, along with a screenshot of a Repl Tree output.  ([Click here to read more about AutomationId](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/uitest-and-test-cloud/#Adding_Support_in_Xamarin.Forms_Apps))

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    var content = new ContentPage
    {
        Title = "XamarinUITest_Images",
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                },
                new Image {
                    Source = "circle1",
                    StyleId = "myStyleID",
                    AutomationId = "myAutomationID"
                }

            }
        }
    };

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
}
```

[image: try enter image description here]

[image: app screenshot]